# Calculate sum of a column in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have the following array

```
    foreach ($reviews as $review){

$sqlreviews[] = array (

'score' => $review['value'] + $review['location'] + $review['service'] + $review['rooms'] + $review['cleanliness'],

);
```

The following echo outputs 11 25 25 25

```
foreach ($sqlreviews as $review1) { 
echo"
".$review1['score']."
";
}
```

How can I sum the above outputs and have the total of 86 to pass it to a variable?

Comment: This question does not contain a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($sqlreviews as $review1) { 
    $sum += $review1['score'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP 5.5's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, you can do something like:

```
$total = array_sum(
    array_column(
        $reviews,
        'score'
    )
);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can do something like:

```
$total = array_sum(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value['score'];
        },
        $reviews
    )
);
```

or

```
$total = array_reduce(
    $reviews,
    function($runningTotal, $item) {
        return $runningTotal + $item['score'];
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get how your array is setup, but you can output the array sum with the [**array_sum**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function:

```
$a = array_sum($array);
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you have an array like this=> ['reviews'] => ('value'=>0, 'location'=>1, 'service'=>1, 'rooms'=>2, 'cleanlines'=>2);

```
$sqlreviews['score'] = $arrayname['reviews']['value'] + $arrayname['reviews']['location'] + $arrayname['reviews']['service'] + $arrayname['reviews']['rooms'] + $arrayname['reviews']['cleanliness'];
```

If you have only one set of data you dont need to iterate....